Bath ceiling & vanity light stopped working when
I was checking outlets & the bathroom GFCI tested neutral/hot reversed. So I changed it with a new Leviton GFCI & wired it correctly & now tests good. Problem is, the ceiling & vanity lights stopped working & blew the bulbs out. Do I need to reverse the wires in the ceiling & vanity lights too?

Lights themselves usually do not care. It is more of a human safety feature. Lights not working can just be a bad connection, but bulbs blowing is more concerning. Pictures of the outlet and light wires is needed. Is the lights and outlet on the same breaker?  The reverse problem might be before this outlet, so fixing it at the outlet might have made stuff worst.

where they some sort of LED bulbs

More info/ pics needed:  When you say the bulbs blew out, exactly what happened?  (Did they explode?  Stop lighting up, and if so, did you swap with known working bulbs or try them in a known working socket?  What colors are the wires from the GFCI to the lights, and which is now connected to what color screw on the GFCI?
